# Allowing Access-Control-Allow-Origin from anywhere (Java and ember.js)

Tags: java, ember.js, jersey, cors, jetty

I am using Java Jersey and Jetty on my server-side and have the following piece of code:

```
    responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, auth-token");
    responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    responseBuilder.allow("OPTIONS");
```

and I'm using ember.js on my client-side and have the following code:

/app/adapters/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://127.0.0.1:20000',

    ajax(url, method, hash) {
        hash = hash || {};
        hash.crossDomain = true;
        hash.xhrFields = {
            withCredentials: true
        };
        return this._super(url, method, hash);
    }
});
```

The combination of the code works that it sends the COOKIE as part of the request and resolves the Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem.

However, my concern is that the "http://localhost:4200" is hard-coded. While it is not a problem until deployment, I suppose this restricts traffic only from http://localhost:4200? It is a web application and **obviously I need to allow access from any client coming from anywhere**. What changes do I need to make to my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> obviously I need to allow access from any client coming from anywhere

I think there is a misunderstanding in here. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` specifies the *server of your client application*.

Does your client application run on a specific origin?

- If yes: There is no problem. Define some `profiles` to your application. By doing so you may define *the origin of the server of your client app* at your production profile.
- If no: You can use `"*"` to accept all origins in your **cors filter**. If this piece of code is written by you, just parameterize the second parameter as to give client's hostname. It should be something like: `request.getRemoteHost();`.

Comment: When using the wildcard you can't use credentials tho.

Comment: I put "*" and indeed threw an error. I have to send JWT as a cookie to the server so I can't use wildcard.

Comment: @ykaragol as you said "Access-Control-Allow-Origin specifies the server of your client application"... I'm relieved to hear this. Yes, my server app will run on a specific origin. So based on what you have said, I won't have any problem at all, right?

Comment: yes, just write the url of the origin/server of your client application. (If the server of your ember app is at the same origin with your java app, you would not face with any cors issues.

Comment: "`*`" is generally used in configuration files for cors filters.You may not need to write that piece of code, you may configure cors filter written for this problem.

Comment: In our production environment, ember.js apps are at the nginx. All java servers are behind that nginx. They share the same origin, so we don't have any cors issues in our production environment. But in development environments we are using cors filters (coming with spring boot).

Comment: @ikevin8me is it ok? Or do you have any issues?